# What structures can be placed with a structure block?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-data-packs

I would like to edit/replace the swamp hut and mineshafts, but I am not sure what the namespace/path is. So does anyone know of a list of the structures that can be placed with the structure block and the proper names to place them?

On the wiki, I was able to find the proper names for Woodland mansion rooms, ocean ruin buildings, and even shipwrecks, but not the two I want most.

For the swamp hut, I know it is called a swamp_temple so I named both the file and the folder that, but it still does not seem to work. I tried swamp_hut and swamp_temple (both with and without the space), both inside and out of a folder etc.

And I assume the mineshaft is something weird like the woodland mansion rooms. I tried "tunnel", which did not work, and gave up.

After hours of research, I cannot find any lists anywhere

Edit, I have renamed the file to something I know works, and I can confirm my NBT file works if I get the name right.

Comment: For a more effective answer, you should present some folder paths that you have tried so far but didn't work. For example, did you have something like `data/aceplante/structures/my_structure.nbt`? Providing full details of your past trials will be very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the structure block wiki (https://minecraft.wiki/w/Structure_Block),
only the following structures have folders in minecraft.jar, and are able to have their parts be placed with structure blocks:

ancient_city

bastion

end_city

fossil

igloo

nether_fossils

pillager_outpost

ruined_portal

shipwreck

underwater_ruin

village

woodland_mansion

coral_crust‌ [BE only]

Or in other words, other structures like desert pyramids, ocean monuments, mineshafts, strongholds, and worldgen features like dungeons and desert wells cannot be modified/placed.